# Can I hook up onto Win32 events in C# application?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, winapi, win32gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle WndProc messages in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf)
>   [P/Invoke tutorials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736227/p-invoke-tutorials)

I writing a window application which needs to use very custom Win32 API. Is there a way I can:

- Call Win32 functions?
- Process custom events like I would do with WinProc() function for Win32?

Comment: Have you tried using [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/)?

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736227/p-invoke-tutorials

Comment: See details here for handling Windows messages in WPF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf. For WinForms, just override WinProc method from Form class and define the Windows messages you'd like to catch.